# How to scale images with transform scale inside box, using css

Tags: html, css

I am trying to make set of pictures( with border radius) to scale on hover. but to stay inside a box and make it look like it is only zooming inside that box not actualy getting bigger on site. I have already tried few thing none of them worked. I ill be really thankful for any advice.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/xnOIN.jpg

```css
     .foto{
       overflow: hidden;
       max-width: 100%;
       border-radius: 25px;
    
    }
    .popis{
       position: absolute;
       bottom: 5px;
       left: 50px;   
    }
    .popis h3{
      font-weight: 600;
      color: white;
    }
    main img{
       filter: brightness(60%);
       width: 100%;
       overflow: hidden;
       border-radius: 25px;
       -webkit-transform: scale(0.9);
       -ms-transform: scale(0.9);
       transform: scale(0.9);
       transition: transform 0.5s, opacity 0.5s;
    }
    main img:hover{
       opacity: 1;
       -webkit-transform: scale(1);
       -ms-transform: scale(1);
       transform: scale(1);
       transition: transform 0.5s, opacity 0.5s;
    }
```

```html
    <main role="main" class="container">

        <div class="row" id="nprace">
            <div class="col-lg-12 col-md-12 text-center nadpis">
                <h2>Lorem ipsum</h2>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="foto col-lg-4 col-md-4">

                    <img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/XZ4V5.jpg">
                    <div class="popis">
                        <h3>Hagendaz</h3>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="foto col-lg-4 col-md-4">

                    <img src="img/hagendaz.jpg">
                    <div class="popis">
                        <h3>Hagendaz</h3>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="foto col-lg-4 col-md-4">

                    <img src="img/hagendaz.jpg">
                    <div class="popis">
                        <h3>Hagendaz</h3>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="foto col-lg-4 col-md-4">
                    <img src="img/hagendaz.jpg">
                    <div class="popis">
                        <h3>Hagendaz</h3>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="foto col-lg-8 col-md-8">
                    <h3>Text</h3>
                    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Vivamus porttitor turpis ac leo. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Fusce nibh. Aenean vel massa quis mauris vehicula lacinia. Nulla quis diam. Etiam quis </p>
                </div>
                <div class="foto col-lg-4 col-md-4">
                    <img src="img/hagendaz.jpg">
                    <div class="popis">
                        <h3>Hagendaz</h3>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="foto col-lg-4 col-md-4">
                    <img src="img/hagendaz.jpg">
                    <div class="popis">
                        <h3>Hagendaz</h3>
                    </div>

                </div>
                <div class="foto col-lg-4 col-md-4">
                    <img src="img/hagendaz.jpg">
                    <div class="popis">
                        <h3>Hagendaz</h3>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

    </main>
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok, think this should do the trick

Just take away the difference from the margin of you image, whenever user hovers over it. This should make it appear centered when zooming.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Test</title>
    <style type="text/css">
        img{
            height: 300px;
            width:300px;
            transition: 0.5s; /*Add transition to make it smooth */
            cursor: pointer; 
            border-radius: 25px;
        }
        img:hover{ 
            margin-left: -20px; /*Take away the difference you want to zoom in (20px in this case)*/
            margin-right: -20px; /*Take away the difference you want to zoom in (20px in this case)*/ 
            margin-top: -20px; /*Take away the difference you want to zoom in (20px in this case)*/
            margin-bottom: -20px; /*Take away the difference you want to zoom in (20px in this case)*/
            height: 320px; /*Change image size on hover*/
            width:320px; /*Change image size on hover*/
        }
        #imgWrapper{
            height: 300px;
            width:300px;
            margin-left: auto;
            margin-right: auto;
            overflow: hidden; /*Set the wrappers overflow to hidden*/
            text-align: center;
            border-radius: 25px;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="imgWrapper">
        <img src="https://jessehouwing.net/content/images/size/w2000/2018/07/stackoverflow-1.png">
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Hey so I already have the overflow thing. But I need it to zoom to middle not to the left top cornor. + I would like to have the border-radius 25pixels.

Comment: Got a test version here. https://cubeit.cz/test/  All i need to do now is making some space between these images. But margin in class .foto isnt really working, bcs it puts just 2 pictures in 1 row.

Comment: Try adding a little padding ("padding: 20px;") to your .foto class. Should add some space around those images

Comment: Actually I see your using bootstrap. Add "justify-content-around" to each row class and it will adjust the space between all contents of that row evenly.

Comment: It does add some space, but then again when I hover it scales to the original size nad i don't want that, I want it to stay the same size the whole time. And just to zoom on hover

Answer (score 0):

You were close, see the comments.

```css
.foto{
       overflow: hidden;
       max-width: 60%; /* Changed for visibility */
       border-radius: 25px;
       width: 20rem;
       padding: 1rem
    }
    .popis{
       position: absolute;
       bottom: 5px;
       left: 50px;   
    }
    .popis h3{
      font-weight: 600;
      color: white;
    }
    main img{
       filter: brightness(60%);
       width: 100%;
       overflow: hidden;
       border-radius: 25px;
       transform: scale(1.1); /* Reset */
       transition: transform 0.5s, opacity 0.5s;
    }
    main img:hover{
       opacity: 1;
       transform: scale(1.2, 1.2); /* Transform X * 1.4 and Y * 1.4 */
       transform-origin: center center; /* Transform from X-center and Y-center */
       transition: transform 0.5s, opacity 0.5s;
    }
```

```html
<main role="main" class="container">

        <div class="row" id="nprace">
            <div class="col-lg-12 col-md-12 text-center nadpis">
                <h2>Lorem ipsum</h2>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="foto">

                    <img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/XZ4V5.jpg">

                </div>
                <div class="foto">

                    <img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/XZ4V5.jpg">

                </div>
                <div class="foto">

                    <img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/XZ4V5.jpg">
                    <div class="popis">
                        <h3>Hagendaz</h3>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="foto">
                    <img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/XZ4V5.jpg">
                    <div class="popis">
                        <h3>Hagendaz</h3>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="foto">
                    <h3>Text</h3>
                    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Vivamus porttitor turpis ac leo. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Fusce nibh. Aenean vel massa quis mauris vehicula lacinia. Nulla quis diam. Etiam quis </p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </main>
```

Comment: Hey, this is almost it, but it still gets bigger and doesn't stay at the size of the NOT hover mode. To be specific, it still scales to sides. As you can see here https://cubeit.cz/test/

Comment: I made some modifications on the width and scales. On the other end, everything in programming is like that: you have to adjust yourself to your need. You just have to modify the values. I am going to recommend something: do not use templates or frameworks. Like here, you are using bootstrap. This is inducing complexity, and is not helping.